# File Sharing Mac-PC results in Permission Changed and Locked Files

Tags: network, windows, permission, file-sharing, smb

Recently I decided to recycle one of my old Macs into a home-file-sharing-server.

The Mac running Yosemite is connected to a router with Ethernet and is running PLEX server. A hard drive is also mounted.
Everything workes fine. I can access the Mac with ARD, start and control downloads with remote Transmission, and Manage my Plex server... everything from work.

Sometimes I download from another Mac on my local network, aiming my server as a destination folder... never had a problem.

But when my wife tries the same from her computer, everything changes.

I Shared two folders. Created her an account and Added her account to the sharing permissions of theses two folders.
So far so good, she can mount those two folders on her PC running W$7.
She can open uTorrent. She can select my shared folders as destination folder for her downloads (after login-in).

But when she creates a new folder into the Shared ones, the Permissions are changing. With Cmd-I, I can see that I'm not even present in the permissions lists (red Wrong-way sign). I have to add myself into the permissions list on my own computer.
Then comes the downloaded files. This one is always lock (lock box checked) and lock icon.

The result is that Plex cannot add the freshly downloaded files and that I have to interfere into a normally automated process which is pointless.

Don't need to add that I am using the "Apply these settings to all content" options... But its not working for New files. I'm using SMB setting for her to access my folders

I have look for answers but can't find one matching my needs.

Please give me a hint if you can,

Regards,

Quentin

Comment: Can you give the output of `ls -l` on one of the shared folders in which she created a sub-folder? ACLs and permissions with Samba shares can get a little dodgy unless you are running OS X Server..

Comment: so I have run a `ls -l` on the folder which contains the Shared Folder. I guess that's what you meant ?

The result is `drwxr-xr-x+` on **staff**.

Is it helping in any way ? You mentioned OsX server. Do you mean that I wouldn't have this issue if I was running OsX Server and not Yosemite client ?
I could definitely do that. But I guess their would still be some settings involve to trick SMB ?

Comment: Can't guarantee that running Server would fix it - I haven't run Yosemite Server - but would be worth checking into. Ownership and permissions on shared folders can be hard to manage without fine-grained ACLs and inheritance settings. (Pre-Lion Server versions had the ACL/inheritance controls for shares.) Standard file sharing using Shared Folders doesn't propagate Group inheritance to sub-folders, which is really what you need since the *Staff* group is only getting `r-x` permissions.

Comment: So what are my options without installing Os X Sever ?
Any solution to propagate the inheritance ?

Comment: I don't know of any ways to propagate permissions automatically for shares on non-server editions. And I'm not sure if there are still those fine-grained controls in Yosemite Server. It would involve locating the documentation for Server and digging into the File Sharing sections to see what controls you would have.

Comment: https://help.apple.com/advancedserveradmin/mac/4.0/#/apdDABA4AF7-8FE4-451B-9B6C-89D6406D2654 shows ACL use and propagation abilities in Yosemite Server.

Comment: Not sure I understand everything :s

Comment: It outlines the permissions settings available. Most important for your case is four levels of inheritance at the folder and file level. That's the fine-grained ACL control that lets you apply specific inherited permissions.

Comment: Ok... Downloading Yosemite Server :)

Answer (score 1):

Thx douggro.

I've just finished solve my problem and you helped a lot. Os X Server was an easy solution. 20 minutes between download and success.

On Yosemite client I already created a groupe yesterday, that I basically called "Sharing".
With the file-sharing Options of OsX Server I had more options to set this groupe as I intended to do, and more particularly by spreading permissions to children files and folders.

OsXServer also allow you to create dedicated folder for groups which is a quite good solutions also. But didn't even needed it since the files-sharing options did really good !

So now my wife can access the server with dedicated rights, download stuff and PLEX catch newly arrived files, on the go !

Thx !